# Suspend workflow from InlineScript block

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to suspend a workflow, from inside an `InlineScript` block:

```
workflow foobar {
    Param([string]$Choice)

    InlineScript {
        switch ($Using:Choice)
            1 { Write-Host "One!" }
            2 { Write-Host "Two!" }
            3 { Write-Host "Suspending worklflow!"; Suspend-Workflow }
        }
    }
}
```

Calling the workflow with `foobar -Choice 3` returns the error:

`The term Suspend-Workflow is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

Is it possible to call `Suspend-Workflow` in this way? How?

Comment: [I'd suggest giving this article a read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psworkflow/about/about_suspend-workflow?view=powershell-5.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not possible to suspend a workflow from inlinescript. Suspending requires the ability to serialize all execution state. The workflow engine was designed to do this but the base PowerShell engine was not.

Answer (score 1):

According to this blog post, Switch statements are not supported in Workflows:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/01/02/powershell-workflows-restrictions/

**Edit:**

Perhaps a nested If would suffice?

```
    workflow foobar {
    Param([string]$Choice)

    if ($choice -eq 1) { 

        InlineScript {Write-Host "One!"} 
    }

    if ($choice -eq 2) {

        InlineScript {Write-Host "Two!" }
    }
        elseif ($choice -eq 3) { 

        Suspend-Workflow 

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think this is applicable to `InlineScript` as the same article you linked explains.

Comment: You're right, jumped the gun a bit. Edited with a more helpful suggestion.